# Opentok individual archive audio is not clear

Tags: video, webrtc, opentok

I have set my archiving as `INDIVIDUAL` I recieve multiple archives per participant. I have 2 problems here:

1. The resolution is not HD, even though I set resolution as `1280*720` in `publisherOptions` the archives in `archive.zip` is never HD quality.
2. The audio is not clear at all, there are alot of breaks in audio. Interestingly the `COMPOSITE` archive's audio is always clear.

Do I need to do some processing before playing the archives?

Answer (score 0):

Tokbox developer here:

1) Please don't pay attention to the file header that indicates the resolution: that value is hardcoded to some fixed number and unrelated to the publisher's resolution because the stream resolution can actually change. If you playback the file, the player should tell what the actual resolution is, at it should change with time. At some point, it should reach 1280x720

2) That shouldn't happen. Which player are you using?